# Get 4 groups of 6 records from the last 24 results

Tags: mysql

I would like to get the average (from each group individually) of 4 groups with 6 records each from the last 24 results. Basically get the average of the first 6 records (from the last 24 records), then of the next 6 records and so on. How can I do that?

Table example:

```
    id |      datetime        | viewer_count
    ----------------------------------------
    1  | 2015-10-31 22:00:38  |    1548
    2  | 2015-10-31 23:00:42  |    1589
    3  | 2015-11-01 00:00:44  |    1589
    4  | 2015-11-01 01:00:37  |    1587
   ... |         ...          |    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a variable to enumerate successive records:

```
SELECT (rn-1) DIV 6 AS groupNo, AVG(viewer_count) AS averageCount
FROM (
SELECT id, datetime, viewer_count,
       @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) var
ORDER BY id DESC ) t
WHERE t.rn <= 24
GROUP BY (rn-1) DIV 6
ORDER BY groupNo DESC
```

If you order by `id DESC` and enumerate consecutive records using a variable, such as `@rn`, then you can get the last 24 records using

```
WHERE t.rn <= 24
```

in an outer query.

You can group records in slices of 6 using *integer division*:

```
GROUP BY (rn-1) DIV 6
```

Finally, using:

```
ORDER BY groupNo DESC
```

you can re-establish initial row order.

**Note:** The above query assumes that your table contains 24 or more records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4360c/1)

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the query for a table where records are added every half an hour? Only getting inaccurate results with `t.rn <= 48` & `DIV 12`